# Word for "music playing in a mall."

Tags: single-word-requests

I just came across a word for "music playing in a mall" in some song's lyrics or an article. Mostly a song(latest pop), can't recall.

Reverse dictionary help?

PS: It might begin with a "P"

Comment: You already accepted Lawrence's answer, but just in case,  [another Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_music#Elevator_music) mentions "piped music" as another word for "elevator music". Maybe you were thinking of that.

Comment: it's simply **"background music"** (note that, unrelatedly, that can also mean the music in films.)  Note that if you look up the defition of the trademark "Muzak", it simply describes it as "background music."

Comment: "Piped music" is another less common term for background music.  And "elevator music" or "waiting music" (mainly on elevators, phones, respectively) is the same sort of thing.

Comment: Brian Eno composed a piece called *ambient music for airports*. Hence, *ambient music* could also be used wrt music in a mall.

Comment: @Fattie: In the most common usage (in the US), it's simply "muzak" with no capital (and spoken in a tone of scorn/disgust).  Like many another example, the trademark has become a generic term.

Comment: Hmm, @jamesqf.  At the local mall, for background music, they just play normal pop music (ie, the actual original versions, ie by Madonna, Justin Bieber, etc etc).  Nobody would call it "muzak", I don't think.  In contrast at some malls they do play "muzak"  (ie, instrumental only, no singing, not the original actual track from the artists, endless loop with no breaks, that soft edgeless sound - muzak. totally different from "original pop tracks" - it has no words, etc.)

Comment: @Fattie: I don't think you appreciate the distinction between "Muzak" and "muzak" as a generic word for the background music played in stores, elevators, &c.  Using the word "normal" WRT pop music implies that you can actually tell the difference: I can't, as the only times I hear it is when it's being used as muzak.

Comment: "I can't ..."  hey @jamesqf.  Muzak is ***instrumental ...  no words***.  It is not the original recording by the famous person.   It has a very soft sound with only one or two keyboard-like instruments.  I'm absolutely certain that you could instantly tell the difference between the Beatles "Yesterday" and the muzak version, or AC/DC's "You shook me all night long" and the muzak version.  It is completely, totally, utterly different.  Heh!  cheers for now

Comment: @Fattie: No doubt I could tell if I listened to the two side-by-side, as it were.  But if I'd never heard AC-DC to know what it sounds like (which I haven't), how would I tell?  Could you tell the difference between say Bach or Handel, and (horrible thought!) Muzak versions thereof?  Background music is something I try my best to tune out, not pay attention to.

Comment: P is for *pablum*...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You might be thinking of *Muzak*:

> Muzak is a brand of background music played in retail stores and other public establishments. In 1981, Westinghouse bought the company and ran it until selling it to the Fields Company of Chicago, publishers of the Chicago Sun-Times, on September 8, 1986. Formerly owned by Muzak Holdings, the brand was purchased in 2011 by Mood Media in a deal worth US$345 million.
>   [- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzak)

It doesn't start with *P*, but it appears that there *is* a song that includes the word *muzak* in its lyrics, and the *band* name starts with P:

> [The Sound of Muzak](https://genius.com/Porcupine-tree-the-sound-of-muzak-lyrics) by Porcupine Tree

Comment: The "P" is silent.  And invisible :-)

Comment: Worth noting that Muzak has become an eponym to some extent, though perhaps not quite as popular as Kleenex, Thermos, or Band-Aid, for any form of background or elevator music.

Comment: @cobaltduck:  And a pejorative by many.

Comment: Muzak is a ***particular type of music***.  It is exactly like saying "Jazz" or "Classical".  It's that strange, "rounded off, softened" for of music that is, well, Muzak.  It's difficult to describe unless you hear it.  By no means is all background music "Muzak".  In the US, it's much more common these days (example - Starbucks, Dunkin Donuts, McDonalds) that they play, simply normal pop songs. (Dunkin Donuts has it's own in=house "radio station", which indeed is a big affair in itself given the size of the chain. They don't play any Muzak at all.)

Comment: Note that Muzak is instrumental only.  If you hear it, you'll know it!  There are a number famous stories about famous musicians (Led Zepplin, etc) being in an elevator, and suddenly hearing one of their famous heavy rock songs .... rendered as "Muzak" !

Comment: @Fattie: But unless you're a fan of the particular genre, it's not easy (or perhaps not even possible) to distinguish between the Muzak version and the originals being played as background muzak, thus in general use the generic lower-case word serves for both.

Comment: In the gym changing rooms recently they were playing a Muzak version of Fauré's Requiem. Definitely distinguishable from the original!

Answer (score 26):

If you want a term that begins with a P and is more formal than "muzak", then the term you're probably looking for is **[Piped Music](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/piped-music)**

> Piped music is recorded music which is played in some supermarkets, restaurants, and other public places. *(Collins English Dictionary)*

Comment: I've always heard it as *piped-in music* in the US. Just *piped* would make me think of organ music.

Comment: @chrylis: If it's called pipes, I'd think of bagpipes, or the similar but not identical Irish Uilleann pipes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uilleann_pipes

Answer (score 18):

Besides *Muzak* the term **elevator music** is common, too. Merriam-Webster has [an entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elevator%20music) for it. Their definition includes music played at retail stores ;-).

At least closely related is the term [**Ambient Music**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_music) which has not been mentioned yet. Brian Eno popularized the term with his album [*Ambient 1: Music for Airports*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_1:_Music_for_Airports) in 1978. The music was explicitly meant to serve as an acoustic background in public spaces.

Comment: *Elevator Music* is also the title of a [whole book about the subject](https://www.press.umich.edu/script/press/8718), by Joseph Lanza.

Answer (score 6):

Lawrence already mentioned the band Porcupine Tree and their song "The Sound of Muzak".
In its lyrics this type of background music is referred to as "Elevator Prozac".

> Hear the sound of music
>   Drifting in the aisles
>   Elevator Prozac
>   Stretching on for miles

Could this be the 'P' you're thinking of?

Comment: Again this is more of a comment, but this thread doesn't stop to blow my mind.

Comment: Those were the 2 words I did not know in that song.

Answer (score 2):

It is music specifically designed for shopping. Shopping Music. Tom Waits calls it out as good music for romantic conversation in the intro to "Better off without a wife" on "Nighthawks at the diner".

> Put a little nice music on, maybe you put on some shopping music,
>   something that's not too interruptive. Then you slide over real
>   nice...

Now granted he's talking about taking himself out on a date, but calling it shopping music evokes the proper emotion in anyone who has ever experienced it.

Comment: Tom Waits taking himself out on a date? Oh boy, that invokes some very bad imagery. Twice the booze, twice the cigarette butts...

Comment: It's a hoot. Give it a listen.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rU-sCw1xnLU

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of live music being played impromptu for donations in a public setting, the word generally used is "busking".